# Difference between before and after middleware in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, middleware

The only thing I know is that I have to do this:

```
$response = $next($request)
// some logic
return $response;
```

if I want middleware after the request is handled by the application and also when I use global middlewares, but I have absolutly no clue why I have to do this (I have noticed that I dont have access to $request->user() for example if I dont declare $response variable using global middeware, but I dont know why). Things i cannot understand are:

- before/after the request is handled by the application - what does it exactly mean (other than one runs before and second after)?
- How global middlewares defined in protected variable in kernel differs from after middlewares or what they have in common (cause rules during creating handle method are similar)?

I have tried to track down the laravel framework code itself but I think my skills are not enough.

Comment: [This article](http://www.codeheaps.com/php-programming/laravel-5-middleware-stack-decoded/) has a good explanation.

Comment: Ahan!! @Bogdan the link does not work anymore

Comment: You can use https://web.archive.org/web/20181212195021/http://www.codeheaps.com/php-programming/laravel-5-middleware-stack-decoded/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about a middleware that checks access control before performing an action. If it's going to deny access, it has to run **before** the request is handled. The request handling is typically what is done in the relevant controller action.

Another example is cookie encryption and decryption. The decryption is done in a **before** middleware so that when you are handling the request, you can read and write to the cookie normally. Then an **after** middleware encrypts the cookie before sending it to the client.

Global middleware runs on every request, as opposed to middleware that is assigned to something (e.g. a route or a controller).